# Подскажите как написать COUNT в postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Всем доброе время суток, есть 2е таблицы
первая содержит id записи у нас это events 
Вторая содержит множество записей одно из полей которой (events_id) ссылается на id в таблице events

Надо подсчитать сколько записей содержатся во второй таблицы с каждым id 
полный запрос выглядит так

```
select
    ev.id,
    name,
    events_id,
    date_start,
    date_stop,
    tpe.id as type_int,
    tpe.description as type_name,
    stat.description as status_text,
    stat.id as status_id,
    loc.description as description_location,
    loc.url_maps as url_maps
from  event.events ev
inner join event.types tpe on ev.type_events = tpe.id
inner join event.status stat on ev.status = stat.id
inner join event.location loc on ev.location_events = loc.id
left join task.tied_of_events tas on ev.id = tas.events_id
```

как мне подсчитать кол-во всех записей возвращаемых tas.events_id и вместо значение этой записи вернуть кол-во записей в таблице с этим id?

Comment: Добавить группировку и соответственно групповую функцию COUNT().

Comment: Ну вот нефига, если я добовляю `GROUP by events_id;` он мне говорит     ERROR: column "ev.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
   Position: 9

Comment: Ну надо сперва подумать, по какому полю группировать, и по какому соответственно считать. А также надо выбросить из выходного набора все поля, не соответствующие требуемому уровню группировки.

Comment: Но мне нужны эти поля для дальнейшей работы

Comment: Если нужны данные разных уровней группировки - нужны два запроса. Как вариант - один будет подзапросом второго. PS. Проставьте алиасы таблиц для ВСЕХ полей своего запроса.

Comment: Что означает "нужны поля для дальнейшей работы" ? вот есть у вас event id 1, для нее есть несколько записей. если все поля нужны - то логично, что на выходе запроса должно быть много записей с этим id, со значениями каждой строки отдельно. Где в этом случае должно быть количество, в каждой из множества записей или все таки запись должна стать одна, но тогда что должно произойти со значениями тех полей где для одного event id есть несколько разных значений ?

Comment: Если первый вариант - много записей и в каждой присутствует поле с их общим количеством - то смотрите "оконные функции" (вроде `count(1) over(partition by event_id)`). Если же запись должна быть одна и в ней количество - то group by, и в любом случае надо определяться с тем, какая же информация должна остаться в этой итоговой записи

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй отдельно посчитать количество строк, потом просто сделать join.
Как на примере:

```
with id_count as (
    select ev.id , count(*) cn
    from event.events ev
      left join task.tied_of_events tas on ev.id = tas.events_id
  group by ev.id
) select
    ev.id,
    name,
    events_id,
    date_start,
    date_stop,
    tpe.id as type_int,
    tpe.description as type_name,
    stat.description as status_text,
    stat.id as status_id,
    loc.description as description_location,
    loc.url_maps as url_maps,
cnt.cn  // кол во строк в  tied_of_events
  from  event.events ev
    inner join event.types tpe on ev.type_events = tpe.id
    inner join event.status stat on ev.status = stat.id
    inner join event.location loc on ev.location_events = loc.id
    inner join id_count cnt as cnt.id= ev.id
    left join task.tied_of_events tas on ev.id = tas.events_id
```